# Save as different file type

Tags: vba, csv, save

I would like to make my macro able to save a xlsx file as csv exactly with the same name when running it.

This is what I tried:

```
ActiveWorkbook.saveas Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
    ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

However, it saves the file as .xlsx.csv (i.e, a file called prices.xlsx is saves as prices.xlsx.csv)
How could I save the file with a different file extension, without the .xlsx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it more failsafe, in case your extension may be xls, xlsm, xlsb, you can do something like this:

```
Dim parts As Variant

parts = Split(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")
parts(UBound(parts)) = "csv"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
    Join(parts, "."), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

It's probably not 100% bulletproof, although I'm struggling to think of a situation where it would not work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it did work and allows to apply the code for different file types, good job!

Answer (score 3):

```
Filename := ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name,".xlsx", ".csv")
```