# How to save Excel sheets as csv with a custom extension?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like save my worksheets from a workbook as separate csv-files, although with a custom extension.

This is the result I am looking for:

Sheet1.xyz
Sheet2.xyz
etc

With the code below I can save all sheets as csv-files:

```
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

    SaveToDirectory = "D:\test\"

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name, xlCSV
    Next

End Sub
```

In the post below an Excel *workbook* is saved with a custom extension:

[Save as different file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618668/save-as-different-file-type)

How can I combine these in order to save the worksheets as csv- (or text-) files with a custom extension "xyz" ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: After `WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name, xlCSV` try adding `Name SaveToDirectory & WS.Name & ".csv" as SaveToDirectory & WS.Name & ".xyz"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

```
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

   SaveToDirectory = "D:\test\"

   For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name & ".xyz", xlCSV
   Next
End Sub
```